# PHP Regex Extract Substring with Quotes and Brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have the following String examples:

```
new myProduct('', 'bbc_609'),
new myProduct('', '35857'),
```

I want to be able to extract just the codes in the second set of single quotes:  bbc_609 or 35857

What I have tried:

```
$str = "new myProduct('', 'bbc_609'),";
preg_match('/ new myProduct('', '  ' (.*?) ''),/', $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

I am getting a parse error so I am assuming that I am not escaping the quotes or brackets properly?

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = "new myProduct('', 'bbc_609'),";
preg_match("/new myProduct\('', '(.*?)'\)/i", $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
\(\s*'[^'\)]*'\s*,\s*'\K[^'\)]*(?=\s*')
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LSzTA3/1)

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the brackets and the quotes otherwise they will be interpreted differently by php and regex.

```
$str = "new myProduct('', 'bbc_609'),";
preg_match('/new myProduct\(\'\', \'(.*)\'\)/', $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```